# Symfony + Nginx + Proxy_pass + Subdirectory : How to rewrite url?

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am trying to step a bit out my comfort zone as programmer and trying to do myself a full setup from a webserver . I could do it using apache, but, I have the need to use proxy_pass because I have a few golang API's . Doing some research I realized I could get better benchmarkers if I also set up a proxy for my Symfony application :

But, to run this symfony app I need to use a subdirectory. So far, I managed to run golang and symfony thru a proxy_pass on ngnix, but, Symfony has not rewrited the routes :

So, when I access http://myip/MYSUBDIR/app_dev.php/myroute all the (background) loaded urls ( for files, scripts, ajax requests, etc ) are like http://myip/app_dev.php/myroute

And of course, I need the 'MYSUBDIR' on the url !

How do I rewrite the url to solve my problem ???

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a vps, php fpm 7.3 and nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

Symfony is on v3.4

/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location /MYSUBDIR/ {



        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_cache mysubdir_cache_setup;
        proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$request_uri";
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale updating error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/mysubdir_cache_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mysubdir_cache_access.log;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            root /usr/share;
    }

    location /goapi/ {

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9003/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and #/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysubdir

```
server {


    listen 8080;

    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

    root /var/www/html/mysubdir/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
       # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
       # current version of your application, you should pass the real
       # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
       # FPM.
       # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
       # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
       # for more information).
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
       # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
       # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
       # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
       internal;
   }

   # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
   # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
   location ~ \.php$ {
     return 404;
   }

   error_log /var/log/nginx/mysubdr_error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/mysubdr_access.log;
}
```

Sure I have both files properly linked on ../sites-enabled/

phpmydmin and goapi locations are working fine

Please, How can I solve this matter ?!